# How to speed up a query which use several string filters?

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection in MongoDB 3.4 to store the contacts of all users from some application. Each contact has a large list of string fields (100+). I use MongoDB but the question is valid for any other engine (MySQL, Elastic Search, etc.)

Almost all the queries to retrieve contacts have the same four base conditions, for example, *user_id*, *base_field1*, *base_field2*, *base_field3* so a I created a compound index with those fields to improve the queries. The base query look like this:

```
db.contacts.find({
    user_id: 1434,
    base_field1: {$in: [0, 10]},
    base_field2: true,
    base_field3: "some value"
}).limit(10)
```

The execution time of the base query is good (less than 2 seconds) but keep in mind that there are 25K contacts which match the base conditions.

However the application lets the user to filter contacts by any other field and even to add any number of filters. All the filters uses *contains* operator so the query look like:

```
db.contacts.find({
    user_id: 1434,
    base_field1: {$in: [0, 10]},
    base_field2: true,
    base_field3: "some value",
    field4: {$regex: "foobar", $options: "i"},
    field5: {$regex: "foobar", $options: "i"},
    field6: {$regex: "foobar", $options: "i"},
      .
      .
      .
}).limit(10)
```

So the execution time is not good (between 9-10 seconds) for our requirements. Also, as you can expect, increasing the number of filters increase the execution time too so:

**Is there any way to speed up the query from a design&query point of view?**

**Is there any other DB engine better than MongoDB to improve this kind of queries?**

Please take in account the following comments and restrictions before reply:

- A Text Index is useless here because if I create a compound text index with all the possible fields but the user filters only by *field4 contains "foobar"* then the result might have contacts which contains "foobar" on *field5*.
- Just create a compound [index with more than 31 fields is not possible in MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Number-of-Indexed-Fields-in-a-Compound-Index).
- Create a simple index for each field doesn't make sense because when the user filters by several fields, only one index will be used by MongoDB. Also you can create [only 64 indexes per collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Number-of-Indexes-per-Collection).
- I actually use a MongoDB shared cluster through a hashed key (user_id) but for the sake of simplification I reduced the problem to the scope of only one shard, I mean, the problem exists even when I add a shard per user.

**Edit:** I changed OR conditions (*field4* OR *field5* ...) by AND conditions which is the real case.

Comment: Where does MySQL factor in? I'm removing that tag as you seem to be searching for a MongoDB answer.

Comment: I think your assumption "I use MongoDB but the question is valid for any other engine" is not correct. Each engine can have different performance benchmarks depending on how it stores/indexes data.

Comment: I'm removing the `elasticsearch` tag as well since this is MongoDB related.

Comment: Could you identify which are the 64 _most commonly searched_ fields, and add an index for each of them?

Comment: @Val I replied the issue in MySQL and the problem is the same. The execution times are obviously a bit different but the principle is the same: the more filters you add, the slower query is. I think it is a common issue no matter what DB engine you use, that is why I extended the question to other engines despite of I use MongoDB. Maybe some experiences (indexes, text search, queries, etc.) from other engines could be applied to MongoDB.

Comment: @VinceBowdren see the 3rd point in the final notes: *Create a simple index for each field doesn't make sense because...*

Comment: @Delmo - but a compound index might be useful; say on userid-basefield1-basefield2-basefield3-field17. The server _might_ be able to use that, if field17 is one of the fields you're querying?

Comment: Yes @VinceBowdren, it should improve a bit but when the user filters by *field17*, *field18*, *field19* and *field20* the execution time becomes bad again. Also, following this approach I should create a compound index for a bunch of fields which has a negative impact on inserts and updates. It looks like there is no "magic" solution for this kind of queries :(